How to "fire and forget" an activity in a ASP.NET core which requires Graph API access?
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web Application, which uses Entra ID OpenID connect authentication, then uses graphclient to access the OnlineMeeting API. All is working.
The web application creates an online meeting with automatic recording, then after the meeting ends the application is accessing to the recording, and downloads it. The application is using Microsoft's React component library to implement the video and chat UI. I can do all the tasks successfully.
Issue:
The recording is created after the meeting ends with some delay. I want to ensure that some execution logic remains active and periodically (1 sec?) trying to get the recording via the graph API. However the end user can simply can just close the browser window, so no more activity in this Web Application session will call any logic in the web application.
Maybe I am wrong, but my idea is to when the meeting ends, then launch a fireandforget execution logic either a Task or Hangfire (in-memory?) and somehow pass the graphclient from the session, (or if serialization needed like Hangfire with SQL Server then the access token. However this all sounds a terrible hack for me.
How can I implement this task? (I mean ensure, that some kept live active logic is waiting the the recording will be available, then do something with the recording)?

Why do you wanna use existing session to download the meeting. Why don't you just use client credentials flow for example to access OnlineMeeting API ? You don't have to worry about passing the token to job - then you can use whatever you want.
